# Android camera zoom in specific region

Tags: android, camera

is it possible to automatically traverse a surfaceview doing zoom in operations?

Specifically:

-Divide a surfaceview in a grid.

-Do zoom in of each grid without any user gesture.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the android in question it may very well be possible, however to be able to do this would require you to be able to run processes alongside the camera if you are looking to do this "live" it may well be easier and effectively simpler to use an image taken on the camera and then perform the given operation you desire.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to open camera and, without user interaction, capture the image and, with the camera zoom (harware), do zoom-in in every cell of the grid. I haven't found any clue of how to this with the Android camera interface.

Comment: It may be possible to do it but I imagine realistically you would have to have the android connected to a pc and then run a script which when the camera app is opened the image is immediately captured and then divided up in to this grid and then zoomed in on. Like I said it may be possible to do it if connected to a pc as then other software would be available to use where the android is limited. I imagine that is the best way to do it although I am no expert and there are some pretty clever people on here.

Comment: I think that this camera behaviour can be achieved in PTZ cameras, but Im not sure how to do it in Android or if the camera hardware of an Android phone can do it.